# Setting zValue in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have a PlotWidget in PyQtGraph on which I draw a LinearRegionItem and set its zValue to 1100 (something large to try and get it to be on top of other items). Then I draw on ImageItems, with no specified zValue and when I do that, the LinearRegionItem disappears. Is there some sort of implicit zValue associated with ImageItems? Or is there a better approach to setting a zValue for an item to ensure it's always on top? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

A new item added has a zValue of 0. If you add them one after another they are stacked on top of each other in the given order.

For example, if you explicitly set the zValue of an item to 10 (using item.setZValue(10) ) it is displayed above the others and not hidden.

```
plotwidget = pg.PlotWidget(title="Spectrogram"))
lin_region = pg.LinearRegionItem( ... )
image = pg.ImageItem()
plotwidget.addItem(lin_region)
lin_region.setZValue(10)
plotwidget.addItem(image)
```

This would show the linear region above the image, even though it was added first.